# A $0$-dimensional ring that is not noetherian

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
[Edit] Martin pointed out that $\dim A = 0$ does not imply that $\Spec A$ is discrete. Therefore I changed the wording of question 2.[/Edit]

---

With dimension of a ring I mean the Krull-dimension.

---

It is well-known that for a commutative ring $A$ the following are equivelent

- $A$ is noetherian and $\dim A = 0$;
- $A$ is artinian.

It is easy to think of noetherian rings that are not artinian ($\mathbb{Z}$). However I cannot find an example of a $0$-dimensional ring that is not artinian.

> ### Questions
>
> 1. What is an example of a commutative ring $A$ with $\dim A = 0$ that is not artinian (or equivalently, not noetherian)?
> 2. A related question is: Give an example of an affine scheme $X$, such that $X$ is discrete as topological space, but $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is not noetherian/artinian.
> 3. Yet another question: Why does the converse of proposition 8.3 in Atiyah-MacDonald fail for a ring $A$ with $\dim A = 0$? (The proposition says that artinian rings have finitely many maximal ideals.)

I have tried various constructions, but they all fail somehow.

Comment: $dim(A)=0$ does not imply that $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is discrete. Instead, it implies that $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Martin, ok. Then I made a mistake somewhere. Actually I am very interested in an example of a non-noetherian ring $A$ for which $\Spec A$ is discrete.

Comment: Ok, it appears that my flaw of reasoning was exactly that spectra of $0$-dimensional rings need not be discrete.

Comment: Now, I have also answered Q2 in my answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Take any compact totally disconnected Hausdorff space $X$ (for example the Cantor set, or the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$). Then $\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{F}_2)$ is a ring whose spectrum is homeomorphic to $X$. In particular, this ring is zero-dimensional, but this ring is noetherian iff $X$ is finite.

More generally, a commutative ring is called von Neumann regular when for every $x$ we have $x^2 | x$ (in particular, boolean rings qualify). Equivalently, every localization at a prime ideal is a field. In particular, they are zero-dimensional (in fact, they are precisely the reduced zero-dimensional rings). It is easy to check that these rings are closed under infinite products.

In particular, an infinite product of fields is a zero-dimensional ring, which is not noetherian. If the index set is $I$, the spectrum is the space of ultrafilters on $I$.

EDIT: It is even more trivial to give non-reduced examples. If $V$ is any $k$-module, then $A=k \oplus V$ is a $k$-algebra (with $V^2=0$). Then $A_{\mathrm{red}}=k$ is a field, in particular $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is just a single point. If $V$ is not noetherian as a module, it is clear that $A$ won't be noetherian as a ring.

Comment: Thanks for answering Q2. I was looking in a totally different direction, but this is indeed a nice example.

Answer (score 19):

The quotient of $\mathbb Q[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ by the ideal generated by all products $x_ix_j$  with $1\leq i\leq j<\infty$ is an example.

Comment: Nice example, Mariano.  Somehow, I have the feling it is not the last time we are seeing it:)

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but I am confused - why is this ring zero dimensional? For $i\in \mathbb{N}$ aren't the ideals $(x_j\vert j\neq i)$ prime with quotient $\mathbb{Q}[x_i]$? So this ring would have dimension 1... Even if I made a silly mistake here I don't see how it could be von Neumann regular.

Comment: I am modding out by all products $x_ix_j$ with *any* $i$ and *any* $j$. In particular, $x_i^2$ is zero in the quotient.

Comment: ...so there is exactly one prime ideal, the one generated by the variables, so that the Krull dimension is zero.

Comment: Ah, thanks - my bad... I for some reason was reading $i<j$.

Comment: More in general, thisi example works for any field $\mathbb{K}$ instead $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you take infinitely many copies of a field?

Comment: I thought I had a prove that, that will not work. Maybe I made a mistake. Can you prove yours?

Comment: You can find a proof in my answer.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I argue as follows. It is not noetherian because the chain of ideals $I_n=<e_i>_{1\leq i \leq n}$ is ascending and never stabilizes ($e_i$ is the $\infty$-ple having $1$ at the i-th place and $0$ elsewhere). It is of dimension $0$ because every ideal is product of ideals (general in any product of rings) and a quotient of my ring is a domain iff is a field, so every prime is maximal.

Comment: No, the ideals are more complicated. They correspond to filters on the index set.

Comment: Wow, really? I confess I have always thought it was true. But where does the argument saying that for every element in the ideal, all its components also lie in the ideal because you can multiply the element by $e_i$ (at least in the countable-index set-case)? Do you have an example of an ideal in $\prod_\mathbb{N}k$ for $k$ a field which is not of the form I wrote? Thanks!

Comment: Sequences with finite support.

Comment: This is a very simple answer. To prove the prime ideals are maximal, just note that this ring is Von Neumann regular. The quotient by a prime ideal is a Von Neumann regular domain,  end it is easy to show this is a field. So prime ideals are all maximal.

Answer (score -3):

A3.
A Local ring has one maximal ideal, but it's not artinian in general (for example, $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$).

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ is not $0$-dimensional.